# Orthogonal vector in two dimensions

Tags: vector

Maybe this is really basic, but I couldn't figure it out.

I would like to find the "hat vector" of a vector I defined: it's a vector orthogonal to the given one, assuming two dimensions. So for instance if I create a vector `a = {1, 2}`, I would like to use some function which gives `{-2, 1}` as the output.

Comment: I think it's OK to leave this as a valid question - but only after changing the wording to clarify what "hat vector" means here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's already built-in. It's called `Cross`.

```
Cross[{1, 2}]
```

Output is

> {-2, 1}

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
foo[v_]:= ({a, b} /. Solve[{a, b} . v = 0, {a, b}])[[1]]
```

Comment: `foo[v_] := ({a, b} /. Solve[{a, b} . v == 0, {a, b}])[[1]]`