# What is the best way to compute the set of vectors normal to a given one?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector

For 2D vectors, computing the vector orthogonal to a given $v$ is straightforwardly done using `Cross`, as for example shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60739/27539).

However, `Cross` does not seem to work for more than two dimensions, and I couldn't find any function giving a complete set of normal vectors to a given $v$.

For example, I'm looking for a function that, given `v={1,0,0}`, will give me back `{{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}`, or some other equivalent set of vectors (that is, I want a basis for the orthogonal space $v^\perp$).

An easy way to do this in 3D is with something like:

```
normalVecs[v_] := Cross[v, #] & /@ IdentityMatrix@3 // Orthogonalize // Select[Norm@# > 0 &];
normalVecs @ {1, 0, 0}
```

but using `Cross` does not generalize to more than 3 dimensions.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it just `NullSpace[{v}]` that you ask?

Comment: @MeMyselfI Ah! I knew there had to be some function doing this, but didn't think of looking with that name. I think that would be the natural answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

general solution

```
normalVecs[vec_] := Module[{l = Length@vec}, 
Cross[vec,##&@@#]&/@ Subsets[IdentityMatrix@l,{l-2}] //DeleteCases@Table[0,l]]  


normalVecs[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

> {{0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,-1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,-1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0}}

Comment: Note that, unlike `Nullspace[{v}]`,  this does not produce a minimal basis of the orthogonal vector space. See for example `normalVecs[{1, 1, 0}]` which outputs two vectors that are the same up to an overal constant. It is clear that the built in `NullSpace` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

One can find a set of orthogonal vectors, orthogonal to each other and to the given vector v, using `NullSpace[{v}]`. (Credit goes to MeMyselfI, see their comment on the question.)